# How to use Linq instead of foreach to Group and Count

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have 2 Lists, one for Players and another for Coaches.

To count number of Players belong to a Coach, I used:

```
  var g = AllePlayer.GroupBy(play=> play.coachNumer);
  foreach (var grp in g)
  {
      foreach (Coach co in AlleCoaches)
      {
          if (co.coachNumer== grp.Key)
          {
              co.NumOfPlayer= grp.Count();
          }
       }
  }
```

Now I want to know if there is a nice way to put the lover parts with "foreach" in a nice Linq syntax to avoid this "foreach" loops.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlleCoaches.ToList()
.ForEach(n=>n.NumOfPlayer=AllePlayer.Where(n=>coachNumer==n.coachNumer).Count());
```

Comment: very quick and dirty :)

Comment: is AlleCoaches is a List you doesn't need make it ToList().

Answer (score 2):

You could change the statement around a little bit. Since ultimately you want to change a property on each coach, it's easiest to loop through that list, as in:

```
foreach (Coach co in AlleCoaches)
{
    co.NumOfPlayer= AllePlayer.Where(p => p.coachNumber == co.coachNumber)
                              .Count();
}
```

Comment: so much easier and symper!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a simpler approach:

```
var query = AllePlayer.GroupBy(player => player.coachNumer,
                               (coach, players => new {
                                   Coach = coach,
                                   Count = players.Count() }));
```

That will give you a sequence where each element is the coach and the number of players for that coach.

Then you *could* iterate over the result, and assign the value into `Coach.NumOfPlayer`, but do you really need to? If you do, this will do it:

```
foreach (var pair in query)
{
    pair.Coach.NumOfPlayer = pair.Count;
}
```

Personally it doesn't feel like "number of players" should be part of the `Coach` type to start with...

Answer (score 0):

```
var g = AllePlayer.TakeWhile(play=> ( play.coachNumer!=null));
```

You may take whatever logic you need but syntax would be the same.

```
var count = g.Count();
```